# Uploading multiple photos to folder and their paths to database through a single click

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, file-upload

I am having trouble with making logic for uploading three picture at the same time to database and their paths to database.
i am using three textboxes for the images titles, 3 file upload buttons and a submit button.

here is what i have tried so far:

```
 protected void Button1_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         using (Property_dbDataContext context = new Property_dbDataContext())
         {

                 Property_image image = new Property_image();


                 image.prop_id = "1";
                     image.image_title = _ImageTitle1.Text;
                     image.image_title = _ImageTitle2.Text;
                     image.image_title = _ImageTitle3.Text;

                     string imagename = _PictureUpload1.FileName.ToString();
                     string imagepath = "wp-content/uploads/2013/05/" + imagename;
                     _PictureUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(imagepath));
                     image.image_url = imagepath.ToString();

                     context.Property_images.InsertOnSubmit(image);
                     context.SubmitChanges();         

         }
     }
```

The interface:
[image]

The fileuploader names are: _PictureUploader1, _PictureUploader2, _PictureUploader3
The textboxes names are: _ImageTitle1, _ImageTitle2, _ImageTitle3
The button name: button1

i am not getting whether which loop to use or not use a loop at all.

i want to store the record in different rows like this:

```
prop_id | image_title | Image_url
1       | car         | wp-content/uploads/2013/05/car.jpg
1       | bus         | wp-content/uploads/2013/05/bus.jpg
1       | truck       | wp-content/uploads/2013/05/truck.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

With limited knowledge of your Class Structure / Database Structure :

You essentially want a 1-many relationship in the database, to accomplish this you need to modify the following code :

```
Property_image image = new Property_image();

image.prop_id = "1";
image.image_title = _ImageTitle1.Text;
image.image_title = _ImageTitle2.Text;
image.image_title = _ImageTitle3.Text;

string imagename = _PictureUpload1.FileName.ToString();
string imagepath = "wp-content/uploads/2013/05/" + imagename;
_PictureUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(imagepath));
image.image_url = imagepath.ToString();
```

to be  :

```
Property_image image = new Property_image();

image.prop_id = "1";

image.images.Add(new PropImage() { title = _ImageTitle1.Text, url = _PictureUpload1.FileName.ToString() });
image.images.Add(new PropImage() { title = _ImageTitle2.Text, url = _PictureUpload2.FileName.ToString() });
image.images.Add(new PropImage() { title = _ImageTitle3.Text, url = _PictureUpload3.FileName.ToString() });
```

And change your Property_image class to be the following :

```
class Property_image {
    public string prop_id {get; set;}
    public List<PropImage> images { get; set; }
}
```

And also add a PropImage class :

```
class PropImage {
    public string title {get; set;}
    public string url {get; set;}
}
```

Because you want a 1-many relationship, you also need to have a 1-many relationship in your Class structure, i.e. an ID can have multiple Images (title + url), so we need to create a list of Image objects inside the Class